# Need help getting a background to show through some text in a more complex way than clipping offers

Tags: html, css, clipping

See the attached image for what I am trying to acheive.

Basically I need the background image to come through the text, except where the text overlaps off the faded panel. This needs the text to become the same colour/opactity as the panel itself.

This is giving me a headache but would like to see how far/what solutions could achieve my goal.

Thanks, Harry.

[image]

---

EDIT 1: Here's a codepen if you'd like to test anything https://codepen.io/itsharryfrancis/pen/XVagep

I've tried using this with it but it does

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

---

EDIT 2: I am going to leave a codepen here that is the latest version of what I have so far for anyone that may want to see it in the future.

https://codepen.io/itsharryfrancis/pen/goxVQP?editors=0100

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Hello! Yes sorry I should have been a bit clearer on that front. So far I just have a very quick mock up of the example so I can try different things, so code wise there's not much to look at (I'll put a codepen together so people can have a go at getting it working if they please). The only thing's I've come close to so far is using the webkit clip but it's isn't going to help as it just adds a background to the text, rather than making the background of the container visible just through the text.

Comment: @JonathanChaplin will make a codepen for this now. 2 mins.

Comment: Here you go guys: https://codepen.io/itsharryfrancis/pen/XVagep

Comment: @HarryFrancis, I'm fairly certain there is no way to do this, even with JS. I think your only option will be to make the white panel and the text into a PNG and set that on top of the background.

Comment: You won't be able to format _one single_ text node differently based on which part of the text will be displayed inside a container element and which one outside ... you'll have to start by making that "two texts" (repeat it via a pseudo element), and then position them accordingly so that you get that "panel overlap" effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example that implements required look, but it uses relatively new [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property that is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) in IE and Edge. This issue can be resolved by using SVG clipping instead (or as fallback), but I hope that this is enough for the start.

```css
.example {
    width: 600px;
}

.example {
    background: url('http://dummy-images.com/nature/dummy-1024x576-Waterfalls.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.text {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 1.0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.part1, .part2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.part1:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}

.part1 .text {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: url('http://dummy-images.com/nature/dummy-1024x576-Waterfalls.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.part2 {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    z-index: 3;
    clip-path: polygon(400px 0px, 100% 0px, 100% 100%, 400px 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="part1"><span class="text">Stack<br>Overflow</span></div>
  <div class="part2"><span class="text">Stack<br>Overflow</span></div>
 </div>
```

**UPDATE:** I've realized that initial version have misaligned background under text. Updated version fixes this issue, but at a small price: `.text` elements are **required** to have `width: 100%` as it allows to align backgrounds. It will cause a need to add some `padding` in a case if text should be additionally aligned.

Comment: This looks tasty! I'll have a proper look through it tomorrow and try implenting it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Nice idea with the overflow part of the text - the second part that might be impossible is getting the text background to line up with the actual background. I'll see what I can do. Thanks again!

Comment: I've just realized that background on the text is not aligned. I found a way to fix this issue, but it will lead to some limitations, I will update answer now

Comment: Awesome - I've added it in and it's working nicely. The only issue is when the background-size: cover; on .example moves to stretching based on the height. This then means the image behind the text is widths based and the main background is height based, offsetting the images. Will see what I can do to solve this. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Unfortunately there is only one thing can be done about `background-size: cover` - you can prepare your backgrounds in a way that it will be squeezed vertically, not horizontally. Backgrounds are synchronized horizontally but not vertically so tweaking size of your background image will help. Also please mark answer as accepted to let other people know that this solution actually solves your question.

Comment: Hi Flying, I managed to get it working as best as I can by changing both background sizes to 100%. It means their might be some white space on the top and bottom but works pretty well! Thanks for your help. Here's a codepen with what I ended up using https://codepen.io/itsharryfrancis/pen/XVagep

Comment: I've cleaned it up a bit and got it to this point now. Might be nice to include in your answer if you want: https://codepen.io/itsharryfrancis/pen/goxVQP?editors=0100

Comment: I think it will be better to include this link as update directly to the question because question is visible better for the visitors.